# Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable Class

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong with my code below. I looked at many threads and I am still not able to fix this issue. It keeps throwing the message `Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable Class`

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim i As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveSheet.Name = "Data"
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set myrange = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
Worksheets.Add

Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:= _
    xlDatabase, SourceData:=myrange)
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B3"), TableName:="PivotTable1")

With pt

        With .PivotFields("Provider Name (for charge)")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
        End With

.CalculatedFields.Add "Net Charges", "=Charge-ChgCorr"

.CalculatedFields.Add "Net Payments", "=Pymnt,UP-PayCor,UPC"

.CalculatedFields.Add "Total Adjustments", "=Contract WO, WOC+Other WO,WOC"

With pt
    With .PivotFields("Net Charges")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Net Payments")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 2
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Total Adjustments")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 3
    End With
End With

End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without seeing the Excel workbook, but you should double check that the names of the PivotFields you've specified are correct.

You might want to try stepping through your code to see exactly which line it's breaking on.